# Accessing all elements of a row in python float array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have searched long and hard and cannot find a way to do this.

```
x = random.normal(100,100)
```

This is a variable X of type float. I want to pass all the elements of the first column as X coordinates and the elements of the second column as Y coordinates to the `matplotlib.pyplot` function. How do I do it ?
Also how to determine the shape of a float array ? In this case it is clearly 100x100 but since float objects do not have a `float.shape` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `np.random.normal(100,100)` is a simple, single float...

Like so?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal((100,100)*100) # 2 * 100 values = 200 values normalized around 100

x = data[0::2] take even as X
y = data[1::2] take uneven as Y

plt.scatter(x,y) 
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot from data]

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate slightly on @Patrick Artner's answer...

```
x = random.normal(100,100)
```

This generates one random variable from a normal distribution with mean = 100 and standard deviation = 100. To see the answer more clearly, you could specify keyword arguments as

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=100, scale=100)
```

Note: loc = mean and scale = standard deviation.

See numpy's documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

To answer your question about how to determine the shape of a float array, you simply call the .shape function on a float array. For example:

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 2))
print("The shape of x is %s" % (x.shape,))
```